# Database encyption with Entity Framework Core/ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I want to store encrypted data in the database. I am using the Entity Framework and ASP.NET Core MVC.

I read about DataProtection: `services.AddDataProtection().ProtectKeysWithDpapi();`

But when I am not mistaken, this is not intended to be used for persistent data, just for cookies and stuff.

Are  there any ASP.NET Core services I can use to encrypt my database/entity data? Or some database encryption for Microsoft SQL Server that work well with EF Core?

Since querying encrypted data is also a performance and logic issue I would limit it to specific fields only in the database.

Comment: The main issue is less the encryption itself (which can be implemented in one way or another), but rather the key management process. Where is the key stored? What happens when the key is compromised? How key rotation is done without re-encrypting the data? I'd suggest to read the [MSSQL DEK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/default-settings?view=aspnetcore-2.2) article and [this blog post](https://matthewmcgiffen.com/2018/03/28/rotating-tde-certificates-without-re-encrypting-data/) about key rotation.

Comment: The Data Protection API isn't really intended for database-level encryption. You could use it for that, but you'd have to manually encrypt and decrypt when roundtripping to the DB. You also run the risk of not being able to decrypt your data because of key rotation. There's technically an unsafe decrypt functionality provided, but you really shouldn't rely on that. SQL Server itself has encryption facilities, so you should look into that, so that the encryption is done at the actual database.

Comment: @Chris Pratt Yeah that's why I am asking about some other possible solutions in conjunction with the entity framework. I will take a look into encryption on the DB level.